# Why is yarn giving me, please use yarn version 1.10.1?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying to build vsocde (so code - OSS) on **MacOS 12**. I followed the steps, using the latest commits, and then when I go to install dependencies using yarn I get the following error (in log file).

```
[1;31m*** Please use yarn >=1.10.1.[0;0m

[1;31m*** Please use yarn to install dependencies.[0;0m
```

Though if I run.

```
yarn -v
```

The output is

```
3.1.1
```

Comment: The code [appears to be here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/158cd6da42eebc440849d976da444176b0437fbf/build/npm/preinstall.js#L23), and appears to assume Yarn 1.x; it will fail on any Yarn with a minor version less than 10, which would include `3.1`.